# Enabling mobile hotspots through restricted accounts (6.0.1)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab E
OS: Android 6.0.1

Question: How can I allow a restricted account I've created on my tablet to turn the mobile hotspot on and off? Is this only accessible via admin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The hotspot can programmatically be turned off through apps. For example, an app called CamScanner takes camera photos of receipts or invoices and can email them as PDFs or image files. If there is no 4G signal available, it will enable WiFi, which disables hotspots by default. This will effectively disable the hotspot despite not being on an admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know a different way, you can access only via admin. I'm sorry, let me know if I helped you.

Comment: May I know how this suffices as an answer? It appears to be a comment.